# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'D:'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, bcp

I trying to call a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspImportDepartment2]
    @filePath nvarchar(255),
    @formatPath varchar(255),
    @countInsert Int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sqlstmt nvarchar(255)
    DECLARE @results table (result xml)

    --Build the Dynamic SQL Statement to get the data from the xml file
    SET @sqlstmt= N'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ( BULK ' + @filePath + ', FORMATFILE=''' + @formatPath + ''', FIRSTROW=1, MAXERRORS=0)AS xmlData'

    -- Insert the results of the dynamic SQL Statement into the temporary table variable.
    INSERT INTO @results EXEC (@sqlstmt)

    select @countInsert = count(*) from @results

    --DECLARE @xmlDoc XML
    --SELECT @xmlDoc = result FROM @results
END
GO
```

And execution code:

```
DECLARE @count1 int

EXEC [dbo].[uspImportDepartment2] @filePath = 'D:\test_1.txt',
           @formatPath = 'D:\test_1_c.fmt', @countInsert = @count1 OUTPUT

SELECT @count1 as AAAA
```

But it throws an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'D:'.

Can somebody tell me what the problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: The \ (backslash) is an escape character.  Make your path with 2 of them \\

Answer (score 1):

Quotes are missing , write as:

```
    SET @sqlstmt= N'SELECT xmlData.* FROM OPENROWSET 
    (BULK ''' + @filePath +''',
     FORMATFILE=''' + @formatPath + ''',
     FIRSTROW=1, MAXERRORS=0
    )AS xmlData'
```

You can learn more about the syntax of `OPENROWSET` function from here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190312(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Use [`QUOTENAME(@path, '''')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) instead, it will handle also embeded quotes, if any. As is now, the code is a SQL Injection vector.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think that you need a space before "AS"

```
SET @sqlstmt= N'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ( BULK ' + @filePath + ', FORMATFILE=''' + @formatPath + ''', FIRSTROW=1, MAXERRORS=0) AS xmlData'
```